# How can I get the application to pause and update a bar chart in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sorting, windows-forms-designer

I'm attempting to draw out a quicksort algorithm in its sorting process. Here is the code for quicksort.

```
public void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j)
        {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            
        }

        /* This function takes last element as a pivot, places
        the pivot element at its correct position in sorted
        array, and places all smaller (smaller than pivot)
        to left of pivot and all greater elements to right
        of pivot */
        }

public int partition(int[] arr, int low, int high)
        {
            // pivot
            int pivot = arr[high];

            // Index of smaller element and
            // indicates the right position
            // of pivot found so far
            int i = (low - 1);

            for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++)
            {

                // If current element is smaller
                // than the pivot
                if (arr[j] < pivot)
                {

                    // Increment index of
                    // smaller element
                    i++;
                    swap(arr, i, j);
                }
            }
            swap(arr, i + 1, high);
            return (i + 1);
        }

public void quickSort(int[] arr, int low, int high)
        {
            if (low < high)
            {

                // pi is partitioning index, arr[p]
                // is now at right place
                int pi = partition(arr, low, high);

                // Separately sort elements before
                // partition and after partition
                quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);
                quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);
                updateBarChart(arr);
            }
        }
```

`updateBarChart(arr)` takes an array and draws it out on the barchart control. The code is below:

```
public void updateBarChart(int[] selectedArray)
        {
            chart1.Series["Data"].Points.Clear();
            int placement = 0;
            foreach (int point in selectedArray)
            {
                this.chart1.Series["Data"].Points.AddXY(placement, point);
                placement += 1;
            }
        }
```

The way I was able to get insertion sort to draw the bar chart in a step-by-step process was using `Task.Delay(some value)`, where `some value` is an integer based off of a track bar. It pauses for a specified amount of time, *then* draws out the bar chart, which allows the user to view the sorting process happen in front of their face. This methods works fine with insertion sort and I'll list the code below this paragraph, but when I try it with my quicksort functions, it doesn't work. The array will be completely sorted, THEN drawn after already being sorted. The user doesn't get to watch the sort taking place, which defeats the purpose of a sorting visualizer. I'm assuming the issue stems from the fact that the quick sort sorting process involves recursion, which throws the `Task.Delay` call off track. That's my assumption, but I really don't know.

Below is my insertion sort function.

```
public async void InsertionSort(int[] intArray)
        {
            int i = 1;
            int j = 1;
            int placeHolder = 1;
            while (i < intArray.Length && stopStatus == false)
            {
                j = i;
                while (j > 0 && intArray[j - 1] > intArray[j])
                {
                    placeHolder = intArray[j];
                    intArray[j] = intArray[j - 1];
                    intArray[j - 1] = placeHolder;
                    j--;
                    updateBarChart(intArray);
                    await Task.Delay(sortSpeedBar.Value);
                }
                i++;
            }
```

I've tried using a timer control, where I have the timer essentially run for a second, then try drawing out the bar chart, but ultimately, it did the same thing that task.Delay did: completely sorting it, then drawing the final sorted value. Also, I'm aware that in order quick sort to draw in a step-by-step process, that I have put the `updateBarChart` method in a proper spot for the updating to be accurate. My code doesn't have that in the right spot. I'm simply just trying to solve the thread/recursion problem with `Task.Delay` before I can continue. So does anyone have any ideas.

Finally, just as an example, driver code to run quicksort. And this is running on .netframework 4.7.2

```
Class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] arr = {7, 4, 9, 1, 12, 5, 0, 6, 4};
        int arrayLength = arr.Length - 1;
        quickSort(arr, 0, arrayLength);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind blocking your main thread, you could try Thread.Sleep(milliseconds):

```
public void quickSort(int[] arr, int low, int high)
    {
            ....
            quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);
            quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);
            updateBarChart(arr);
            Thread.Sleep(sortSpeedBar.Value);
        }
    }
```

If you need it to be async, you can also invoke the function on a new separated thread.